# Envelope of signal in time domain

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, envelope

I'm trying to get envelope of a signal.  In an old topic, I found some old code `abs(hilbert(signal))`.

After filtering the acceleration signal in time domain with 1/3-octave-band and using the code from above my signal look like this:

Red -->Hilbert Blue-->Signal

[image: result]
<sub>(source: [1.ii.gl](http://1.ii.gl/gaNtcE9To.png))</sub>

I was expecting something more like this:

[image: example]
<sub>(source: [tugraz.at](http://www.emt.tugraz.at/publications/diplomarbeiten/da_hoebenreich/img56.gif))</sub>

It seems like my envelope doesn't quite fit.

Here's my code for the 1/3-octave-band:

```
Fs = 5000;
N= 4;     
Fc1= 1425;  
Fc2= 1795;  
h= fdesign.bandpass('N,F3dB1,F3dB2', N, Fc1, Fc2, Fs);
Hd= design(h, 'butter');
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: maybe this info will help http://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/examples/envelope-detection.html

Comment: Judging from the provided pictures it looks like your signal has a bias, or has just positive values. The hilbert transform envelope only works for bandlimited signals. You filtering looks right to me, but it does not look like the signal plotted.

Comment: @AndréBergner thank for your reply. indeed singal has only positive values. I have done the hilbert transform step by step from this diagram [link](http://1.ii.gl/VxagHlHQG.jpg). If something is incorrect, please guide me to proper solution.

Comment: @user4378465 This looks wrong to me. After the filter there should directly come the hilbert transform, the half wave rectification is not needed.